# How do you deserialize your own serialized code? (CodeDomSerializer)

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-forms-designer, codedom

I assume custom deserialization is needed. However, neither deserialization method in `SerializableExpandoObjectCodeDomSerializer` is run before this error occurs.

How do you deserialize your own serialized code?

I am serializing a property of a component which is a dynamic object. Properties and values can be added, removed and changed in the property grid at design time.

This class persists design-time changes perfectly:

```
class SerializableExpandoObjectCodeDomSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
    {
        var expandoObject = (SerializableExpandoObject)value;
        var expandoObjectExpression = base.GetExpression(manager, value);

        return new CodeStatementCollection(
            expandoObject.GetDynamicMemberNames()
            .Select(name => new CodeAssignStatement(
                new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(expandoObjectExpression, name), base.SerializeToExpression(manager, (object)expandoObject[name])))
            .ToArray()
        );
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object codeObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Never runs.");
        return base.Deserialize(manager, codeObject);
    }

    protected override object DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, object[] parameters, string name, bool addToContainer)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Never runs.");
        return base.DeserializeInstance(manager, type, parameters, name, addToContainer);
    }
}
```

Resulting in serialized designer code for the `this.autoSerializer.Options` object:

```
// 
// autoSerializer
//
this.autoSerializer.Options.Test = "1";
this.autoSerializer.Options.AnotherSetting = "Chart";
this.autoSerializer.CalculateLayoutID += new System.EventHandler<Techsola.Controls.CalculateLayoutIDEventArgs>(this.autoSerializer1_CalculateLayoutID);
this.autoSerializer.ComponentLayoutLoaded += new System.EventHandler<Techsola.Controls.LayoutLoadedEventArgs>(this.autoSerializer_ComponentLayoutLoaded);
```

When the designer is closed and reopened, if there were any properties saved, this is displayed:

> The designer cannot process the code at line 129:
>   this.autoSerializer.Options.Test = "1"; The code within the method
>   'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be
>   manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the
>   designer again.

How do you cause the designer to make use of your deserialization methods before it tries to parse it and gives up?

Comment: Pretty hard to guess how you even got the serializer to run.  This normally requires a [DesignerSerializer] attribute on the class, you can't change the attributes for ExpandoObject.  I suspect this the core of the problem.

Comment: I should clarify that even though `SerializableExpandoObject` provides similar functionality to `ExpandoObject`, it derives directly from `DynamicObject`.